# mat-checkbox and mat-checkbox header issue in mat-table of Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design

I have a mat-table with checkboxes which will be checked already as per the `API` response and I can check more checkboxes and `click` on Submit, which is working fine but I am getting issues with design I am not getting the header checkbox to show that all the checkboxes are checked.

It has to be look like this

[image: table with all the checkboxes checked hence the header checkbox is also checked]

but even if all the checkboxes are checked already it shows like this
[image: this looks like this you can check that all the checkboxes are checked]

and even with half of the checkboxes are checked already it doesn't behave as it has to be like a mat-table with checkboxes.

Following is the stackblitz link of a demo I created which shows the same problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebckbl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In initialization you need to set selected items as below

```
selection = new SelectionModel<PeriodicElement>(true, ELEMENT_DATA.filter(t=> t.IsAssigned));
```

currently you set selected rows to empty array

```
selection = new SelectionModel<PeriodicElement>(true, []);
```

Check working example here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t56fss

Comment: now even data with `IsAssigned:false` looks cheked checkbox

Comment: @SuhasMandumale Yes, if you need only assigned items just intiate `selection` with  it, check update answer

Comment: thank you very much for the help, i had to make some tweaks to make it work, i made a function as this `SelectedCheckbox(){
  this.selection = new SelectionModel(true,this.roles.filter(o=>o.IsAssigned));  
 }` and called in `ngOnInit()`